# SQL Server Database File and WCF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I have a WCF Service that exposes a method GetCustomers(). The internals of the method uses a Data Layer along with a Business Layer to return a List of Customers. Currently I am using an SQL Server Database file saved on the server. Everything works fine on my local network but I want to move this to the web.

I thought the best method would be to create an IIS WCF Service which makes calls to the current WCF Service's GetCustomers(). I haven't had much experience with the SQL Server Database Files but I figured I would need to move the .mdf file to the IIS WCF Service App_Data folder but I'm not sure how to change the database connectionstring and get all this to work properly. The only thing I can figure is that I will have to re-implement the GetCustomers() method in the IIS WCF Service and point it to the correct database. It seems like I shouldn't have to do this though.

I know that if I where hosting the DB in a full SQL Server implementation that this wouldn't be a problem because the connectionstring wouldn't change. That is not an option at this point.

I think I am making this more difficult than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some bad news - you can't access SQL Server data files directly.  You have to be running SQL Server.

You're taking the Access approach, which does work without any kind of Access Server - you just point your datasource at the file and you're done.  SQL Server files do not work that way.

If your database is small, consider checking out [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx), which has most of the power of SQL Server without the expensive licensing.

Comment: It works locally, is it because when I run it locally on my server in debug mode is it creating a virtual SQL Server to host the DB?

Comment: Depends on what development environment you're using.  Some versions of Visual Studio come with SQL Server Express.